# RabbitMQ (MQTT) how to send answer message from consumer to publisher?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp

I'm trying to find information on how to send a response to a publisher. I want to use the **MQTT** protocol. Is there any way to do this?
I need the publisher to send a message to Rabbit, consumer to receive it, process it and send the result of the work back to the publisher.

On the AMQP protocol, this is implemented using [Remote procedure call (RPC)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html)

Example to AMQP:

```
result = channel.queue_declare(queue='', exclusive=True)
callback_queue = result.method.queue

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='rpc_queue',
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                            reply_to = callback_queue,
                            ),
                      body=request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct publisher -> subscriber or subscriber -> publisher communication in MQTT. Everything is published to a topic.

Starting at MQTTv5 there is the option to include details of a reply topic in a published message. This is an optional field.

This would mean that the publisher can set a topic it will listen for a response message on. This can be either a generic topic, or one that is specific to that particular initial message.

If you can set this field will depend on both clients and the broker supporting MQTTv5.